# difference between specific ID rows

Tags: r

I have some data which looks something like the following:

```
# A tibble: 100 x 3
# Groups:   Section, Quintiles [20]
   S        Q                 R
   <chr>    <chr>         <dbl>
 1 business quintile_1 -0.0167 
 2 business quintile_1  0.0202 
 3 business quintile_1  0.00797
 4 business quintile_1  0.0492 
 5 business quintile_1  0.0193 
 6 business quintile_2 -0.0393 
 7 business quintile_2  0.0159 
 8 business quintile_2  0.0163 
 9 business quintile_2  0.0740 
10 business quintile_2  0.0385
```

How can I take the difference between "business" - "quintile1" and "business" - "quintile5".

So I am trying to create a new "quintile6" which is just the difference between the first and last quintiles. I am trying to spread the data first and have each quintile as columns but I have other variables and it quickly becomes thousands of columns wide so I am wondering if teres a more "simple" way.

Data:

```
structure(list(S = c("business", "business", "business", "business", 
"business", "business", "business", "business", "business", "business", 
"business", "business", "business", "business", "business", "business", 
"business", "business", "business", "business", "business", "business", 
"business", "business", "business", "mgnt", "mgnt", "mgnt", "mgnt", 
"mgnt", "mgnt", "mgnt", "mgnt", "mgnt", "mgnt", "mgnt", "mgnt", 
"mgnt", "mgnt", "mgnt", "mgnt", "mgnt", "mgnt", "mgnt", "mgnt", 
"mgnt", "mgnt", "mgnt", "mgnt", "mgnt", "qualitative", "qualitative", 
"qualitative", "qualitative", "qualitative", "qualitative", "qualitative", 
"qualitative", "qualitative", "qualitative", "qualitative", "qualitative", 
"qualitative", "qualitative", "qualitative", "qualitative", "qualitative", 
"qualitative", "qualitative", "qualitative", "qualitative", "qualitative", 
"qualitative", "qualitative", "qualitative", "risk", "risk", 
"risk", "risk", "risk", "risk", "risk", "risk", "risk", "risk", 
"risk", "risk", "risk", "risk", "risk", "risk", "risk", "risk", 
"risk", "risk", "risk", "risk", "risk", "risk", "risk"), Q = c("quintile_1", 
"quintile_1", "quintile_1", "quintile_1", "quintile_1", "quintile_2", 
"quintile_2", "quintile_2", "quintile_2", "quintile_2", "quintile_3", 
"quintile_3", "quintile_3", "quintile_3", "quintile_3", "quintile_4", 
"quintile_4", "quintile_4", "quintile_4", "quintile_4", "quintile_5", 
"quintile_5", "quintile_5", "quintile_5", "quintile_5", "quintile_1", 
"quintile_1", "quintile_1", "quintile_1", "quintile_1", "quintile_2", 
"quintile_2", "quintile_2", "quintile_2", "quintile_2", "quintile_3", 
"quintile_3", "quintile_3", "quintile_3", "quintile_3", "quintile_4", 
"quintile_4", "quintile_4", "quintile_4", "quintile_4", "quintile_5", 
"quintile_5", "quintile_5", "quintile_5", "quintile_5", "quintile_1", 
"quintile_1", "quintile_1", "quintile_1", "quintile_1", "quintile_2", 
"quintile_2", "quintile_2", "quintile_2", "quintile_2", "quintile_3", 
"quintile_3", "quintile_3", "quintile_3", "quintile_3", "quintile_4", 
"quintile_4", "quintile_4", "quintile_4", "quintile_4", "quintile_5", 
"quintile_5", "quintile_5", "quintile_5", "quintile_5", "quintile_1", 
"quintile_1", "quintile_1", "quintile_1", "quintile_1", "quintile_2", 
"quintile_2", "quintile_2", "quintile_2", "quintile_2", "quintile_3", 
"quintile_3", "quintile_3", "quintile_3", "quintile_3", "quintile_4", 
"quintile_4", "quintile_4", "quintile_4", "quintile_4", "quintile_5", 
"quintile_5", "quintile_5", "quintile_5", "quintile_5"), R = c(-0.0166774158167082, 
0.0201596769556875, 0.00796992085297743, 0.0492147329548896, 
0.019344865533839, -0.0393260514127627, 0.0159402689787551, 0.0162507344633192, 
0.0740337591014227, 0.0384769820770539, -0.0302717090017819, 
0.0254691625247841, 0.0122239330016886, 0.0446599436180717, 0.0289436320423226, 
-0.0308599365345965, 0.0219191738217161, 0.0176853257846887, 
0.0456353457446462, 0.0341367113786865, -0.0143715467524916, 
0.0393541248460465, 0.00956169994553254, 0.045506941231113, 0.022679161458704, 
-0.0105046406388283, 0.0113396747037768, -0.036155735142529, 
0.0550687853246927, 0.0269238017499447, 0.0414200760424137, 0, 
0.0369318500161171, 0.05479446798563, 0.0441558659076691, -0.032821835950017, 
0.0359311569482088, -0.139999955892563, 0.0209301561117172, 0.104783609509468, 
-0.155844137072563, -0.0610789265483618, 0.0988630047067999, 
-0.0086556291207671, 0.0815064907073975, -0.0115016167983413, 
-0.12346476316452, -0.0105703119188547, 0.092919297516346, 0.136621922254562, 
-0.0196536407222738, 0.0265621797051281, 0.0121992440563654, 
0.0340947461024625, 0.0114726169959482, -0.0152790856625264, 
0.0265492763632932, 0.0222894305734672, 0.0476030515586719, 0.0257378459646134, 
-0.0400270565959709, 0.0249571957657415, 0.0296065641893266, 
0.0516467535933711, 0.0204032773069533, -0.0385776743255634, 
0.0327908558900147, -0.00581402105550901, 0.0471795087541677, 
0.0316287353740667, -0.0299233697188024, 0.0277489582011476, 
0.0194428538125939, 0.0464771821653864, 0.0257204433555745, -0.0248971471088522, 
0.0182182283776942, 0.0133596019044421, 0.0432659004262889, 0.0221001061009796, 
-0.031518697262207, 0.0191115892525381, 0.0213770552106516, 0.0495591080020083, 
0.0217964101541805, -0.0139142393788832, 0.0127029458612358, 
0.0018533759915124, 0.0760172229180238, 0.0367249979117247, -0.0347955894141082, 
0.0380760367129327, 0.0177375553170367, 0.0434032638099822, 0.0288078728030292, 
-0.026367978979474, 0.0392411376774867, 0.0154176355104196, 0.040917916701852, 
0.0218273582628919)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), groups = structure(list(
    Section = c("business", "business", "business", "business", 
    "business", "mgnt", "mgnt", "mgnt", "mgnt", "mgnt", "qualitative", 
    "qualitative", "qualitative", "qualitative", "qualitative", 
    "risk", "risk", "risk", "risk", "risk"), Quintiles = c("quintile_1", 
    "quintile_2", "quintile_3", "quintile_4", "quintile_5", "quintile_1", 
    "quintile_2", "quintile_3", "quintile_4", "quintile_5", "quintile_1", 
    "quintile_2", "quintile_3", "quintile_4", "quintile_5", "quintile_1", 
    "quintile_2", "quintile_3", "quintile_4", "quintile_5"), 
    .rows = list(1:5, 6:10, 11:15, 16:20, 21:25, 26:30, 31:35, 
        36:40, 41:45, 46:50, 51:55, 56:60, 61:65, 66:70, 71:75, 
        76:80, 81:85, 86:90, 91:95, 96:100)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: *"How can I take the difference between "business" - "quintile1" and "business" - "quintile5"."* I'm not sure I understand. I assume the vaues in column `R` are the the different quintiles. What value does `"business"` take?

Comment: Apologies for not making myself clearer! I am trying to `group_by` - `S` and `Q` add a "new" `quintile6` which is essentially the difference between `quintile1` and `quintile5` - value in `R` - I ignore `quintle2, quintile3, quintle4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(
  df,
  df %>%
    filter(Q %in% c('quintile_1', 'quintile_5')) %>%
    group_by(S, Q) %>%
    mutate(idx = row_number()) %>%
    group_by(S, idx) %>%
    mutate(R = R[Q == 'quintile_5'] - R[Q == 'quintile_1'],
           Q = 'quintile_6'
           ) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    distinct(S, Q, R)
)
```

Or a `data.table` way:

```
library(data.table)

rbindlist(
  list(df,
       setDT(df)[
         Q %in% c('quintile_1', 'quintile_5'), ][
           , .(Q = 'quintile_6',
               R = R[Q == 'quintile_5'] - R[Q == 'quintile_1']), 
           by = .(S, rowid(S, Q))
         ][, 'rowid' := NULL]
       )
)
```